# C++, Windows Forms Application, Reading from a File

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, readfile, streamreader

I want to read a specific column/line from a file and save those to a variable. 
So far I was able to read the entire text. But I can't get my code to only read a specific line/column. Here is what I have:

```
private: System::Void button6_Click_1(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    Stream^ myStream; 
    OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog; 

    if (openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
    {
        if( (myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr )
        {
            String^ strfilename = openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1->FileName;
            String^ Readfile = File::ReadAllText(strfilename);
            myStream->Close();  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell more? E.g. what output do you expect and what do you actually get?

Comment: Well right now, if I put ReadFile as the text of a textbox it shows me the entire Text of the Document but without structure.

Comment: what do you mean by structure?

Comment: Which means that the entire Text is put together without space inbetween. But what I really want is to be able to put a=first column of the first line;        b=second column first line;      c= third line,first column; .....

Comment: Yeah, But my problem is I only know C++. Do you know a good C++ GUI Programming tool? One which is as easy to use as the Windows Forms Application from VIsual Studio?

Comment: @Bachus92: If you know C++ (which I doubt, or you would be talking about the string processing techniques you know and asking how to use them with .NET strings -- or you would just be using normal C++ classes for file I/O and parsing), then you should find C# really easy to pick up.  And if you don't know C++ well, you may not find C# easy, but you'll still learn it faster than learning advanced C++ and then the C++/CLI stuff that WinForms requires in addition.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Ben. I will have a look at the C# things

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your own parser.

I.E: Use StreamReader::ReadLine and than you may you String::Split to split all data into columns.

But you never told us what you define as a column...